# Add foreign key constraint to existing table with data in a Visual Studio database project

Tags: sql-server-2014, database-project

I have a Visual Studio database project hitting a SQL Server 2014 database. I need to create a child table for an existing parent table. The parent already has the foreign key column and I need to add the constraint to the new parent table (the FK is on the child and pointing to the parent). I would like to preserve the data.

Currently, the deployment process creates the new table and the foreign key.  The post deployment script adds the child records to the new child table.

My problem is that the FK fails because the child records have not been added.
I can't add the child records in pre-deployment because the table does not exist at that point.

I can't disable the constraint in the pre-deployment because it is getting created in the deployment.

This seems like a common occurrence. Is there an established way to do this?

Comment: Need some clarification. `I need to add the constraint to the new parent table` You mean to the new *child* table? `the FK fails because the child records have not been added` That shouldn't happen, unless you're putting the constraint on the parent table which seems backwards.

Comment: You are correct.  I updated the questions.

Comment: You can avoid this problem (and many others) by putting the FK constraint in the child table. The parent table should not have references to the child tables otherwise you create a "which came first, the chicken or the egg"-type situation.

Comment: I have a table that I call the child.  It has a statusID column.  We have data in it.  Later, we created a table with the allowable statues that I am calling the parent.  Now the statusID column in the child needs and FK constraint pointing to the new status parent table.  I can't seem to get this setup in the database project so it will deploy without loosing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not be an issue.  By default a database project creates constraints with the NoCheck option - meaning SQL Server will not validate the data.  Then, after postDeploy it will check the constraint.  Take a look at you deployment script and it will validate this.